# Is it possible to integrate heuristic algorithm with Anylogic?

Tags: anylogic

I am planning to use ant colony optimization (ACO) to optimize the layout design of a building. I want to use Anylogic to derive the performance of a certain layout design in each iteration of the ACO algorithm and finally obtain the best solution.

Is it necessary to use the APIs of anylogic to realize this idea ?
If the answer is Yes, then , it is possible to change layout design in Anylogic in each iteration of ACO automatically through API?

Answer (score 1):

To use a customized optimization algorithm, the optimization experiment obviously doesn't work because it uses its own heuristics.

You can do that only with a custom experiment. In this custom experiment you will generate the ACO and run the simulation as many times as needed and collect the results to feed the next iteration.

I have done this with Artificial bee colony, cuckoo search and genetic algorithms to optimize systems, so it should be the same for you.

Nevertheless since you are trying to optimize a layout, you will have to smart on how you define your objective function restrictions and search parameters... but that's off-topic

Comment: Thanks! May I ask how did you realize heuristic algorithm with Anylogic custom experiment in more details? Should I write code in a Java IDE with the APIs provided by Anylogic?

Comment: I don't think I can, the amount of details is too much... but what I suggest is to start by checking the examples in the help documentation on how to create a custom experiment, and then you will have to learn a bunch of JAVA if you don't know already and then yes you will have to use AnyLogic's APIs depending on what your model uses...

Comment: Thanks for helping !

Comment: You would help if you explained how the layout is built. If its an image or autocad then you cant change it. But using the elements of anylogic yes you can

Comment: My idea is to get the optimal spacial configuration of the functions in a building, for example, meeting room, reading room, office and so on. So, I think I have to change the coordinates of the functions automatically in each iteration of ACO, and the area of the functions must fit the structure of the building, the behavior pattern (destination) of people should change correspondingly according to the new layout, is this possible using Anylogic?

Comment: it is possible... but it seems you have to learn quite a bit to discover the possibilities there are too achieve that